# Short read Permission denied during Checkout branch in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, bitbucket

I am using bitbucket for version Controlling and for operation on this i use `Android studio` for Push,pull and fetch Code.
But, when I go for Checkout branch I got error:

```
short Read permission denied
Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
```

Before i got this error i have added some files in `.gitIgnore`

```
.gradle
/local.properties
.idea
/workspace.xml
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
*.iml
```

Even after this when i try to add untracked file With

> command git add .gradle/2.4/taskArtifacts/cache.properties.lock

But this show

```
error: short read Permission denied
error: xyz/.gradle/2.4/taskArtifacts/cache.properties.lock: failed to insert into database
error: unable to index file xyz/.gradle/2.4/taskArtifacts/cache.properties.lock
fatal: updating files failed
```

so what is issue? and how can i resolve?

Answer (score 0):

[image: source directory]

dont checked this one, make source directory for writable

Answer (score 0):

Few files seems to be a result of building the project, thus should not be tracked.

You could remove the unneeded files from git using git rm --cached command

Run the following command to resolve the issue.

git rm --cached "Path of cache.properties.lock file"